# Facebook Graph API With iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Has anyone been able to implement Facebooks Graph API in a native iPhone Application?

The documentation is pretty sparse when it comes to iPhone integration, but the calls to get users information looks a lot more light weight than the previous method of using FBConnect.  So i would like to use it.

I have seen a few posts about but none explain you you would implement the login button as we did previously with FBConnect?

If any one has achieved this or can offer me any pointers that would be brilliant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently using a UIWebView to authenticate with Facebook's Graph API as described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/). However, that doesn't really allow any interaction with the application, e.g. showing a loading dialog or error message. I tried to intercept the `webViewDidFinishLoad` whenever I get a response from Facebook and show an `UIAlertView` with an error message when something goes wrong. The problem is, that Facebook already changed one of their URLs, so my string comparisons didn't work any more.

At the moment I'm not going to invest more time into this, because a SDK for Android has already been announced during Google I/O (will be released very soon) and the iPhone SDK is rumored to be released during WWDC.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/).
I implemented sharing in my app in few hours.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using a UIWebView to authenticate with Facebook's Graph API as described
http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/